# Resume Optuna study from most recent checkpoints

Tags: python, pytorch, hyperparameters, optuna

Is there a way to be able to pause/kill the optuna study, then resume it either by running the incomplete trials from the beginning, or resuming the incomplete trials from the latest checkpoint?

```
study = optuna.create_study()
study.optimize(objective)
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can resume an optuna study by using the `load_if_exists=True` .

For example, if you have a study named `'example-study'` and an SQLite file `example.db` you can:

```
study = optuna.create_study(study_name='example-study', storage='sqlite:///example.db', load_if_exists=True)
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=3)
```

You can rerun all the `FAIL` trials by:

```
for trial in study.trials:
    if trial.state == optuna.trial.TrialState.FAIL: 
        study.enqueue_trial(trial.params)
study.optimize(objective)
```

And also, re-evaluate the last trial:

```
study.enqueue_trial(study.trials[-1].params)
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=1)
```

will run the objective function with the incomplete trial parameters.

Comment: Does this resume the interrupted trial from the latest checkpoint?

Comment: What do you mean by checkpoint? It reruns the objective function with the FAIL trial parameters.

Comment: resume the training of the ml model within a trial from a checkpoint. So the training doesn't need to run from start.